# Terraform, why use kubernetes as a extra layer?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I read a lot of documents on the internet. They describe the best combination is Terraform and Kubernetes.
Use Terraform for provisioning and Kubernetes for pod management

If I need to scale then I say to Terraform add new containers. So why Kubernetes ?
Is it more as a monitoring tool in this case, Kubernetes? I mean I can't say to Kubernetes I need more containers it will get in conflict with Terraform.

I don't understand why use the extra layer of Kubernetes.

Comment: where did you read that terraform can create containers?

Comment: a terraform provider has docker so it use that to create a container. but still it's not clear why use kubernetes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) is a tool for provisioning infrastructure across cloud providers, that lets you describe the infrastructure you would like to provision as code (Infrastructure as Code or IaC). You run it, infrastructure is provisioned and that's it.

On the other hand, [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) is a container orchestration engine. It orchestrates worker nodes, where pods are scheduled. It takes decisions on:

- Scheduling: Where the pods should be scheduled to make sure that their resource (CPU / RAM) requests are satisfied
- Service discovery: How one service can communicate with another one
- Self healing: Takes action when a pod is not healthy and restarts it. In addition, it takes action if a worker node is not healthy.
- Autoscaling: Automatically provisions new replicas when the load for your service is high
- Version rollouts: How new versions are deployed and old versions are terminated

These are just some of the features of Kubernetes, and you can check for more of its features in the "Kubernetes Features" section of [this page](https://kubernetes.io/).

Terraform can help you provision your infrastructure, but when your workloads are container-based, then you need a container orchestrator. This is where Kubernetes fits in.

Comment: thank you. But how can it not be conflicted when auto scaling is happening in Kubernetes it add a new pod to it. The infrastructure has changed by Kubernetes , Terraform doesn't know. i get conflict? not?

Comment: Reading the comments below the initial question, I understand that you are referring to the [Terraform Docker provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/index.html) . If I understand correctly, this provider allows you to create containers in Docker. Let's consider the scenario that you create a container with this provider and the application crashes. Will it be restarted? What if the node crashes? What if you would like to deploy a new version without causing downtime to the service? These are problems that a container orchestration engine like Kubernetes helps with.

Comment: oke i understand what you are saying about status of the pod and monitoring it and downtime that's clear to me. but the auto scaling part i'm still in the dark about it, because in my mind it change the infrastructure

Comment: Regarding autoscaling, the usual practice is that when you configure it (whether it is for VM instances / nodes or pods), you configure the minimum and maximum number of replicas that you would like and then leave it up to the autoscaler to configure the current number of replicas depending on the load. As the current number of nodes in autoscaling is impacted by the load and changes over time, it's something that cannot be accurately depicted as code (e.g. in Terraform or Kubernetes). That's why the practice there is to set the minimum and maximum for it.